# Routes to fake a Structure

Tags: routes

I'm building a site with loads of complex itineraries. Entries are in a channel for various reasons, but I want to split the data across subpages, with a URL structure like:

```
/itinerary/name-of-itinerary
/itinerary/name-of-itinerary/dates-prices
/itinerary/name-of-itinerary/gallery
/itinerary/name-of-itinerary/etc...
```

I want to route everything through my `_views/itinerary/index` template, and then just have a bunch of includes (dates-prices, gallery, etc...) in my index, something like:

```
{% include ( '_views/itinerary/' ~ craft.request.lastSegment ) %}
```

In my routes.php I've got:

```
'itinerary\/(?P<slug>[^\/]+)\/([^\/]+)'                 => '_views/itinerary',
'itinerary\/(?P<slug>[^\/]+)'                           => '_views/itinerary',
```

So everything is routing fine to `_views/itinerary/index`. Trouble is, I get a 404 for anything other than */itinerary/name-of-itinerary* because Craft uses the last segment to resolve the entry, which is exactly what you'd want normally. But if the last segment is 'dates-prices' or 'gallery' I'm screwed.

Have I set this up right? Is there a more efficient and complete way? Any help much appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The route/template for '/itinerary/name-of-itinerary' will be defined in the section's settings, so it's the others you need to deal with.

I'd add this route to your routes.php file:

```
'itinerary/(?P<entrySlug>[-\w]+)/(?P<subpageSlug>(dates-prices|gallery|etc))' => '_views/itinerary/index',
```

And then in '_views/itinerary/index' I'd include these conditionals:

```
{% if entry is not defined %}
    {% set entry = craft.entries.section('itineraries').slug(entrySlug).first() %}
{% endif %}

{% if not entry %}
    {% exit 404 %}
{% endif %}
```

On your subpages, the entry model object won't be available by default so you need to check whether it's defined, and if not define it.

Comment: Outstanding Jamie, thanks a lot. Totally makes sense now.

Comment: This is also worth a read: http://buildwithcraft.com/docs/routing/   In your case, #6 would apply here: If you setup your template structure like your URLs, Craft will display the proper template based on the URL. Handy in some instances.